# Can't update existing records in my SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have made a separate class named DatabaseHelper.java and want to make a simple table named sensors.

I wish to update the table using name as a where. But I can't seem to make it work. Please check my code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Readings.db";
public static final String SENSORS_TABLE_NAME = "sensors";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_ID = "Id";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_1 = "Reading1";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_2 = "Reading2";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_3 = "Reading3";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_4 = "Reading4";
public static final String SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS = "Status";

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME + "(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + "STRING" +
                            SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + "STRING," + SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + "FLOAT," +
                    SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + "FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + "FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + "BOOLEAN)"
    );
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setVersion(1);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertSensor(String name, boolean status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Name", name);
    contentValues.put("Reading1", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading2", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading3", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading4", 0);
    contentValues.put("Status", status);
    db.insert("sensors", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(String Name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where Name="+Name+"", null );
    return res;
}

public boolean updateSensor (String Name, float Reading1, float Reading2, float Reading3, float Reading4, boolean Status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Reading1", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading2", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading3", 0);
    contentValues.put("Reading4", 0);
    contentValues.put("Status", Status);
    db.update("sensors", contentValues, "Name="+Name, new String[]{Name});
    return true;
}
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
public boolean updateSensor(String Name, float Reading1, float Reading2, float Reading3, float Reading4, boolean Status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("Reading1", Reading1);
    contentValues.put("Reading2", Reading2);
    contentValues.put("Reading3", Reading3);
    contentValues.put("Reading4", Reading4);
    contentValues.put("Status", Status);
    db.update("sensors", contentValues, " = ?", new String[]{Name});
    return true;
}
```

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE  =

Still not working -.- getting tired

Uninstalled the app and reinstalled it multiple times.

**[EDIT]**

Code still not working:

```
public boolean updateSensor(String Name, float Reading1, float Reading2, float Reading3, float Reading4, boolean Status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SENSORS_COLUMN_1, Reading1);
    contentValues.put(SENSORS_COLUMN_2, Reading2);
    contentValues.put(SENSORS_COLUMN_3, Reading3);
    contentValues.put(SENSORS_COLUMN_4, Reading4);
    contentValues.put(SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS, Status);
    db.update("sensors", contentValues, "Name = ?", new String[]{Name});
    return true;
}
```

The error this time is:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Reading1 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE Name = ?

**[EDIT]**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME + "(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT" +
                    SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + " REAL," + SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + " REAL," +
                    SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + " REAL," + SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + " REAL," + SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + " INTEGER)"
    );
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setVersion(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table creation is wrong: you mess a bunch of spaces

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME + "(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + "STRING" +
                        SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + "STRING," + SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + "FLOAT," +
                SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + "FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + "FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + "BOOLEAN)"
);
```

And

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME);
```

Should be

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME + "(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + 
    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT" +
    SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + " TEXT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + " FLOAT," +
    SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + " FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + " FLOAT," + 
    SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + " BOOLEAN)"
);
```

And

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME);
```

Note: Keeping your code well formatted would help a lot.

---

You also miss some **'** when dealing with string values:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where Name="+Name+"", null );
```

And

```
db.update("sensors", contentValues, "Name="+Name, new String[]{Name});
```

Should be:

```
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where Name='" + Name + "'", null );
```

And

```
db.update("sensors", contentValues, "Name='" + Name + "'", new String[]{Name});
```

My advice would be to use **bound parameters** (that syntax which usus the **?** placeholders and a String array to replace them one by one).

---

After making all the code modifications, just uninstall and reinstall the app.

---

**[EDIT]**

You changed your code (why?!), therefore invalidating half of my answer - I hate when this happens!! I rolled back to your original post.

OK, now seeing your update code... it's **wrong**!

This is the correct syntax

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

This

```
db.update("sensors", contentValues, DATABASE_NAME + " = ?" + Name, new String[] {Name});
```

should be

```
db.update("sensors", contentValues, "Name = ?", new String[]{Name});
```

Comment: It helped, but there is still an error in update method. Please check.

Comment: Now have set the update function as following:

db.update("sensors", contentValues, DATABASE_NAME + "=" + Name, null);

Comment: N.Stein Still not working. The error shown is: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: sensors (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE Name='Accelerometer'

Comment: Of course. You have now to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: Please tell what was the purpose of using  new String[] {Name} as an argument in the update method?

Comment: The purpose is that so you don't have to pass the **'** string delimiters and don't have to double the eventual apostrophes in your strings, since Android does it for you. Possibly, you mixed the techniques.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88291/discussion-between-mohsin-anees-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: So what should it be?

Comment: I edited my answer - Please **don't change** your original post, just **add edits** to it

Comment: My fault: I forgot to write the field name: `"Name = ?"`. See my updated answer

Comment: A New error

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Reading1 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE Name = ?

Comment: This one relates to your table creation command, which has some errors. Let me see it.

Comment: Don't edit my answer. Edit your question. And don't re-post the question.

Comment: **Each time** you modify your table structure, you have to uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: I haven't edited you answer. Have edited the question to include table creation. What is wrong with it?

Comment: we could have started a new thread through my re-posted question focusing on the new errors. We have already acheived a lot through this thread.

Comment: You haven't replied for a while to my question. What is the matter?

Comment: No. you edited my answer - I reverted it back, Then I edited your question witht the table creation code taken from your duplicate question.

Comment: I then told you: **Each time** you modify your table structure, you have to uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: The latest problem that I am facing is mentioned in the comments of the second answer. Please help

Comment: You are behaving like a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)... Stick with a method and sove that. Don't change method every now and then! I'm trying to help you for 5 hours... I'm starting to get sick.

Comment: Now: **HOW** did you get this: `UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE Name = ?Accelerometer`? Obviously enough, you can't attach `Accelerometer`, And not even `'Accelerometer'`.

Comment: Finally Corrected it :P Thank you Frank.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. Please look at the storage classes that must have each value stored in a SQLite database:
https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html
1. onCreate

> "CREATE TABLE" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME +
>   "(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT," +

look at: creat table --> column-def --> column-constraint
AUTOINCREMENT is only one key-word

> SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + "STRING" + SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + "STRING," +

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
There is no datatype STRING and also not, if you look at the affinity name examples.
Take TEXT, or, if you wan't to give the length, VARCHAR(length)

> SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + "FLOAT," + SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + "FLOAT," +
>   SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + "FLOAT," +

"FLOAT" is all right and it converted into "REAL"

> SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + "BOOLEAN)"

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).(1.1 Boolean Datatype)
I think, your statement may be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + SENSORS_TABLE_NAME + 
"(" + SENSORS_COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
SENSORS_COLUMN_NAME + "TEXT" + 
SENSORS_COLUMN_1 + "TEXT," + 
SENSORS_COLUMN_2 + "FLOAT," +
SENSORS_COLUMN_3 + "FLOAT," + 
SENSORS_COLUMN_4 + "FLOAT," + 
SENSORS_COLUMN_STATUS + "INTEGER )"
);
```

2. "setVersion" and "setLocale" in onCreate
   I do not know if that's necessary. 
   In the constructor you have giver the version 1:
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
   Please look at reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper 
   Better is to take a string for the version, becourse an upgrate was taken when you have a new version.

   public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

And than:

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

Comment: You missed many spaces in the create table. And apart from all your changes. It still gives the error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Accelerometer": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE sensors SET Reading3=?,Status=?,Reading2=?,Reading1=?,Reading4=? WHERE Name = ?Accelerometer

Comment: I am using update method like this in the main code: db.updateSensor("Accelerometer", event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2], 0, true);